# Google Sheets - ArrayFormula - XLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

so I have this situation:
I have dates (mmm-yy) in one row (horizontal) and other dates in one column (vertical) I'm trying to match them and if the dates match, then ArrayFormula-XLOOKUP but since the result cell may overwrite the next cell with formula, I've got Circular dependency detected.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtCJv.png)

Please check attached image, I need some advice on how to workaround this issue.

I've tried arrayformula with xlookup, also possible with filter but don't know how to avoid circular dependency.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75426005/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference `F2:F` points to **column** `F`, starting in cell `F2` and extending all the way to the bottom, while you apparently want to point to **row** `2` starting in cell `F2` and extending all the way to the last column.

To fix that, replace `F2:F` with `F2:2`.

Comment: Right. This question is about a circular reference. The lookup issue is a different question that will require a different solution. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741) and do not modify your requirements after you have received an answer. Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.